# Averaging multiple dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 5-6 dates and I want to average them. How can I do it?

Example Data:

```
2021-11-03 12:00:00
2021-11-04 12:28:00
2021-11-05 11:57:00
2021-11-06 12:16:00
2021-11-07 12:08:00
2021-11-08 12:27:00
```

I want to average the hours here.

(12:00:00+12:28:00+11:57:00+12:16:00+12:08:00+12:27:00)/6 = 12:12:40 (Average)

`Select avg(date_) from table;` is not working.

Comment: Do the datetime-values represent elapsed time? Your formula example doesn't seem to represent the definition of an average to me.

Comment: What is the average of time? What is the expected result?

Comment: Hello there. Yes you are right. It would be /6. @Sam020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess this is something expected

```
select 
 sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(time(time_value)))) time_only_avg, 
 from_unixtime(avg(unix_timestamp(time_value))) date_time_avg
from times
```

data

```
create table times (
  time_value datetime
);
insert into times values 
('2021-11-03 12:00:00'),
('2021-11-04 12:28:00'),
('2021-11-05 11:57:00'),
('2021-11-06 12:16:00'),
('2021-11-07 12:08:00'),
('2021-11-08 12:27:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the average time:

```sql
SELECT 
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        (
            TIME_TO_SEC(TIME("2021-11-03 12:00:00")) + 
            TIME_TO_SEC(TIME("2021-11-04 12:28:00")) + 
            TIME_TO_SEC(TIME("2021-11-05 11:57:00")) + 
            TIME_TO_SEC(TIME("2021-11-06 12:16:00")) + 
            TIME_TO_SEC(TIME("2021-11-07 12:08:00")) + 
            TIME_TO_SEC(TIME("2021-11-08 12:27:00"))
        ) / 6
    ) as result 
;
```

Result

```
12:12:40.0000
```